# sim800l only receiving SMS after serial monitor is started otherwise not receiving

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

I am using SIM800L and Arduino Uno.

The programme is working fine when I turn the serial monitor on using Arduino IDE but when I start the Arduino board by using the adapter it is not receiving anything. I have blinked LED on receiving SMS.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial wire(3, 2);
String  Grsp;

void setup()
{
   wire.begin(9600);    
   Serial.begin(9600);       
   wire.println("AT+CMGF=1"); 
    wire.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); 
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);   
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); 
  delay(1000); 
    digitalWrite(8, LOW); 


   delay(100);
}


void loop()
{


  if (wire.available()>0)
  {
        Grsp = wire.readString(); 
     Serial.println(Grsp.length()); 
     Serial.println(Grsp); 

     if(Grsp.length() > 100)
     {
       Serial.println("if crossed"); 

      digitalWrite(8, HIGH); 
       delay(1000); 
        digitalWrite(8, LOW); 

      }




}


}
```

Comment: Do you have any common ground 'GND' between arduino and sim800l module. UART works when there is TX RX and GND terminals are connected between both modules. When you connect it with PC and open your terminal the both got supply from PC thus have common GND connection.

Comment: thank you so much Vaibhav you made my day,it was same as you said i used common GND on breadboard.